# I want to change this to what is written in the array every time a next question button is pushed

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

So I have 4 areas in the HTML: Questions, Notes, Button1, Button2.
I have an Object with values for each in their own arrays:

```
var list = {
    1: ['This is question 1', 'These are notes 1', 'this is answer 1A', 'this is answer 1B'],
    2: ['This is question 2', 'These are notes 2', 'this is answer 2A', 'this is answer 2B']

};
```

When I click the next question button, I want the values to change to the next line of the object
Here is my function:

```
var i = 0;

function nextQuestion() {
    i += 1;    
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = list.i[0];
    document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = list.i[1];
    document.getElementById('btn1').value = list.i[2];
    document.getElementById('btn2').value = list.i[3]; 
}
```

I know that I'm close, but I'm a beginner and don't know what I need to do here.

MAYBE A FOR LOOP???

Thanks

Comment: Have _you_ tried a for/loop? What was the result? There's [ample documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) to help you out.

Comment: `list[i][0];` - use bracket notation for dynamic property access

Answer (score 0):

Change `list.i[0];` to `list[i][0];` and it should work.

Comment: I just tested this in console its working for me. "I" has to be 1 or 2 in your example for this to work.